# How to create a scallable background for text which is in div using css

Tags: css, scalability

I want to create a `div` like below.

[image]

And the `html` is

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
  <div style="background-color: rgb(236, 236, 236); border-radius: 100px; width: 80%; height:80%; padding: 50px">
    <h2 style="width: 100%; height: 100%" />Text</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

This work fine in 100% page view but if i zoom in or out the page the background of the 'text' `div's` shape is changing. Can you help me to fix this. Basically I want a scallable background for the `div`.

Comment: Without a fixed size to the div this is problematical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element...

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

:root {
  --val: 200%;
}

h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 50px; /* adjust as required - or align some other way*/
  position: relative;
}

h2::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: var(--val);
  padding-bottom: var(--val);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: lightgrey;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Text</h2>
```

Comment: can you explain a little bit about `--val: 200%;` Please, Just for my knowledge purpose :)

Comment: It's just a CSS Custom Property (also known as a CSS Variable). It allows you to set a property value once and use it in many places. In this instance, becuase the width and bottom padding have to be the same I used a variable. If you want a different value you can change it in `:root` and it updates all the other times it's used.